# Filming Location: Fox Hills Crematory in Law & Order: Criminal Intent

Tags: film-location, law-and-order-criminal-intent

Anyone know where the Fox Hills Crematory in the [Law & Order: Criminal Intent episode "DEAD"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0629524/) (S2:E1) was filmed?

It looks an awful lot like the carriage house of the Bartow-Pell Mansion/Museum in the Bronx. The building, the driveway, the benches, the field beyond the driveway when the camera pans away from the building.

I tried googling but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Oh! You appear to be right! Look at these two images. You can clearly see the arch behind the fake front door, and you can match up the stones.
[image: http://mybigfatfreakinlife.blogspot.com Slide Show II]

[image: www.jhpokorny.com Conservation project]

Comment: Ah yes, now seeing a still from the episode, you can look at the light/dark patternings in the stone, and it is definitely the same building. Cool!